# Problema ao enviar email pela aplicação

Tags: java

Estou tendo problemas ao fazer uma programa simples para fazer com que minha aplicação envie um email.

Main

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws EmailException, IOException {

        ConfiguracaoEmail emailConfig = new ConfiguracaoEmail(new Filial("matriz", true));
        emailConfig.setServidor("smtp.gmail.com");
        emailConfig.setRemetente("emailFrom@gmail.com");
        emailConfig.setTitulo("Teste");
        emailConfig.setCodificacao("utf-8");
        emailConfig.setAutenticacao("emailFrom@gmail.com");
        emailConfig.setSenha("senhaEmail");
        emailConfig.setPortaSMTP(465);
        emailConfig.setTLS(true);
        List<String> emails = new ArrayList<String>();
        emails.add("emailTo@gmail.com");
        try {
            SendMail mail = new SendMail("Teste", " - envio email", emails, emailConfig);
            mail.start();
        } catch (EmailException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

A classe ConfiguracaoEmail é apenas uma classe auxiliar para guardar as informações de configuração.

Classe SendEmail

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException;
import org.apache.commons.mail.HtmlEmail;

public class SendMail extends Thread {

    private HtmlEmail email;

    public SendMail(String subject, String message, List<String> mailTo, ConfiguracaoEmail config) throws EmailException, IOException {
        this.email = emailConfig(config);
        email.setSubject(subject);
        addTo(mailTo);
    }

    private void addTo(List<String> mailTo) throws EmailException {
        for (String mail : mailTo) {
            email.addTo(mail);
        }
    }

    public HtmlEmail getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(HtmlEmail email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    private HtmlEmail emailConfig(ConfiguracaoEmail cfg) throws EmailException {
        HtmlEmail email = new HtmlEmail();
        email.setDebug(cfg.getDebug());
        email.setTLS(cfg.getTLS());
        email.setSSL(true);
        email.setHostName(cfg.getServidor());
        email.setFrom(cfg.getRemetente(), cfg.getTitulo());
        email.setCharset(cfg.getCodificacao());
        email.setAuthentication(cfg.getAutenticacao(), cfg.getSenha());
        email.setSmtpPort(cfg.getPortaSMTP());
        email.setSSL(false);
        return email;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            email.send();
        } catch (EmailException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

Alguém tem ideia do que pode estar acontecendo? Ele não acusa nenhum erro mas o email não é enviado. (Obs: O código não é totalmente esse. Eu peguei apenas a parte referente ao email)

Comment: Será que o e-mail foi enviado e foi parar na caixa de SPAM do e-mail destinatário?

Comment: Olhei e não está sendo enviado para a lixeira.

Answer (score 1):

Faltou chamar o método ***send***?

```
public SendMail(String subject, String message, List<String> mailTo, ConfiguracaoEmail config) throws EmailException, IOException {
        this.email = emailConfig(config);
        email.setSubject(subject);
        addTo(mailTo);
        Transport.send(email, this.email, "my-password");
    }
```

Documentação: https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/

Answer (score 0):

Eu olhei em outro código de exemplo e o problema é a linha que executa o seguinte comando: email.setSSL(false); no método emailConfig. Eu comentei ele e funcionou. Obrigado.